# How represent a java functional interface in a component diagram

Tags: java, uml, functional-interface, component-diagram

My class have a field Map that references a functional interface.

```
public abstract class AbstractResourceAgent{

protected final Map<String, IInvokeOperation> resourceOperations;

}
```

then i extend that class and create and add anonymous intances of that IInvokeOperation to that Map like this:

```
public class AgentImplementation extends AbstractResourceAgent{

    @Override
    protected void describeResourceInvokeOperations() {

        setOperation("someName", (AgentOperationTarget agentOpTarget) -> {

            //do something...

        });

    }
}
```

Would that even show on a component diagram?

Answer (score 0):

You can make implementation details show on a component diagram by attaching a classifier with the `<<use>>` stereotype.  This is from the spec (*Superstructure* v 2.4.1):

[image]

There's no reason that you couldn't put the base class in there too if you felt it was important to do so.